# How to change preview value in form input without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have form simple like this..

[image: This a screenshot]

And this for code

```
<form action="aksi.php?opsi=edit&aksi=update" method="post">
    <input name="cabangID" type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>

    <div class="form-group"><label>Image (link)</label><input type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" name="image_cabang" value="'.$row['image'].'"/>
        <a href="'.$row['image'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['image'].'" width="420" height="275"></a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Now, I want to improve code like this.. ***When I change Image link, preview image change automatically without page refresh***..
What is the code that I can use? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (change input field to https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUHMf.png for example and click 'Change' button):

```js
    function fnOC()
    {
   var oim,oin;
   
   oim=document.getElementById('idImg');
   oin=document.getElementById('idInput');
   oim.src=oin.value;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Image (link)</label><input id='idInput' type="text" class="form-control input-xlarge" name="image_cabang" value='http://www.vemix.net/MorningGloryFlower.jpg'/>
   <input type='button' value='Change' onclick='fnOC();'/>
   <img id='idImg' src="http://www.vemix.net/MorningGloryFlower.jpg" width="420" height="275">
<!--https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUHMf.png-->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<input type="text" oninput="update(this.value)">
<img id="image" />

<script>
function update(value) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = value;
}
</script>
```

On input update function is called with one parameter - the value of input field then the value is assigned to attribute src of image.

Note that there is no validation, there is no communication with server (you can do it by AJAX) it is just an example of data binding.

You should propably learn JavaScript.